# Print text if match with the total of table

Tags: r

I have two tables like below and want to print the text with matching total of another table. also the last character of text in color format .

for example if total of last column of df1 is 1 then print "work in Progress" with Progress in colour format

```
df1 <- data.frame( " " = c("part1","part2","part3","part4","Total"),
                  t = c(6,  3,  3,  7,NA),
                  s = c(5,  2,  4,  7,NA),
                  u= c(0,   0,  1,  0,1))

df2 <- data.frame( sn= c(0,1,2,3),
                   "goal"=c("I didn't Started", "work in Progress", "all is completed", "this is delivered"))
```

The Text should be like
[image]

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "colour format"? It is not clear what your expected output is. PS: "I haven't started" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the package `crayon` for printing in color, and by choosing some random colors for output:

```
library(crayon)

MyF <- function(df1, df2){
  id <- df1[nrow(df1),ncol(df1)]
  out <- df2 %>% 
    filter(sn == id) %>% 
    select(goal) %>% 
    pull()
  last_word <- word(out, -1)
  first_words <- str_remove(out, last_word)
  if(id == 1){cat(first_words,blue(last_word))}
  else if(id == 2){cat(first_words,red(last_word))}
  else{cat(first_words,green(last_word))}
}

MyF(df1,df2)
```

Comment: its converting all text in  green i want last character in green

Comment: when i am using more conditions like first_words <- str_remove(line, last_word)
  if(id == 1){cat(first_words,red(last_word))}
  else if(id == 2){cat(first_words,blue(last_word))}
  else if(id == 3){cat(first_words,red(last_word))}
  else if(id == 4){cat(first_words,yellow(last_word))}
  else if(id == 5){cat(first_words,brown(last_word))}
  else if(id == 6){cat(first_words,black(last_word))}
  else{cat(first_words,blue(last_word))}

getting Error in blue(last_word) : could not find function "blue"

Comment: Don't forget to load the package `crayon` : `library(crayon)`. If not installed, run `install.packages("crayon")` and then `library(crayon)`